# Background <video> and <html style="overflow-y: scroll;"> generates doubled y-scroll bar in Opera nad Chrome

Tags: css, video, cross-browser, scrollbar, overflow

My problem is the following. I am using a beautiful video background in a  tag for a website. The content does not always overflow on the y-axis. To prevent an ugly jump for the automatically generated y-scroll bar I use to add it from the beginning with CSS:

```
html {
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

That works fine for Firefox and IE. But Opera and Chrome don't recognize the `<video>` tag as size giving and put a second scroll bar besides the y-bar in the height of the generated `<body>` content.

That's also why it's not clever to use `overflow-y: hidden;` on the `<html>` element. Because **I want** the y-scroll bar on the the right browser side from the beginning, to prevent the jump when my `<body>` content overflows.

My `<video>` has this css:

```
#video_background {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  min-width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  z-index: -1000;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: fixed;
}
```

I'd be glad to get it run without js...

Comment: Apply the scroll to the `body` tag, not the `HTML` one.

Answer (score 0):

To form my comment as an answer, you need to assign the `overflow-y: scroll;` to the `body`, not the `html`.

```
body {
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

Comment: **Nope!** Does still generate the double scrollbar. I've tried all of these variants.

Comment: Are you sure there's no element inside the body that's causing the problem?

Comment: The problematic element is the `<video>`. Even if I put it into a `<div>` the `<div>` stays flat with 0px. 

But anyways, if I add a scrollbar to anything there will be a double one as soon as the content overflows the browser height. So it seems when I want to show the scrollbar even before it is needed.